# ConstraintLayout Center views between each other

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How can I set the vertical centre of view1 to the vertical centre of view2 ???

```
val view1 = ConstraintLayout(context)
view1.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(100, 200)
view1.id = View.generateId()

val view2 = ConstraintLayout(context)
view2.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(50, 100)
view2.id = View.generateId()

layout.addView(view1)
lyout.addView(view2)

val cs = ConstraintSet()
cs.clone(layout)

//setting position of view1
cs.connect(view1.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, layout.paddingTop, ConstraintSet.TOP, 50)
cs.connect(view1.id, ConstraintSet.START, layout.paddingStart, ConstraintSet.START, 100)

//setting postion of view2
cs.connect() // ??? no option like "ConstraintSet.VERTICAL_CENTER"
cs.connect(view1.id, ConstraintSet.paddingEnd, view2.paddingStart, ConstraintSet.START, 100)
cs.applyTo(layout)
```

What should i write in ConstraintSet to achieve layout like this :

```
 |------|
 |      |     |---|
 |      | - - |   |
 |      |     |---|
 |------|
```

Comment: totally wrong use. What the meaning of `layout.paddingTop` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you center a view by applying both top+bottom constraints (centered vertically) or start+end constraints (centered horiziontally) or both.

If you want `view2` to be centered vertically with respect to `view1`, you could do that with two `connect()` calls:

```
cs.connect(view2.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, view1.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP);
cs.connect(view2.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, view1.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
```

Of course, there's also a convenience method you could use:

```
cs.centerVertically(view2.getId(), view1.getId());
```

Comment: Wow, so easy, how did i miss it